# Workspace Add-on with installable calendar event trigger stops working with new deployment

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace-add-ons

Our Workspace Add-on uses an installable calendar event trigger.

The trigger is fired whenever there is a calendar update event.

```
ScriptApp.newTrigger('calendarTrigger').forUserCalendar(calendarId).onEventUpdated().create();
```

This works fine until we deploy a new version of our add-on.

Once deployed the installable trigger remains but tied to a previous deployment version.

[image]

Any calendar events are ignored and the trigger sits there doing nothing.

We can code our add-on to remove the trigger and re-add it but this requires our add-on to be opened by a user.

```
ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(tr);
ScriptApp.newTrigger('calendarTrigger').forUserCalendar(calendarId).onEventUpdated().create();
```

The problem is that calendar events are ignored until this manual intervention (which may not occur for some period of time).

How are we supposed to have the trigger update when we deploy a new version of our app?

Comment: Hi, this is working as intended. Take a look at the update in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that with each new deployment, you update the Workspace Addon in the GCP Platform, to do that:

1. Access GCP
2. Marketplace > **Google Marketplace SDK** > App Configuration
3. In the Deploy using Apps Script Deployment Id (first item) update the Deployment Id.

The Deployment Id is found in the Apps Script Project > Deploy (blue button, top right) > Manage Deployments > Pick the active one (on the left) and its Deployment ID is displayed.

Also note that it is helpful that if you create a new version of your script, then I suggest you when you deploy, click on the current version, then on the pen (up top) then "Add new Version". This way there is one deployment with a new version, as opposed to having multiple deployments with various versions active.

Comment: Ah - I see.  So my issue is that I am creating a new deployment for every change.  It sounds like from what you say I can update my currently Live deployment by generating a new version.  That way the new version is pushed out to the users and the deployment in Google Marketplace is not affected.  If this is so then my trigger will continue to work :).

Answer (score 1):

#### Update: Intended behavior:

An update was provided by Google at [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/201438780#comment3), clarifying that this is working as intended:

> This is intended behavior. Workspace add-on triggers installed using older deployments will get disabled if the add-on is updated with a new deployment.
>
> In order to update a Workspace add-on without disabling the current deployment triggers, [edit a versioned deployment](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/deployments#edit_a_versioned_deployment) instead of [creating a new one](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/deployments#create_a_versioned_deployment).
>
> The team will look into improving the UI in order to avoid potential confusion around this.

#### Issue:

The same behavior was reported in Issue Tracker some time ago, albeit in this case referring to time-driven triggers:

- [Workspace add-on time triggers stop executing when new deployment is published](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/201438780)
- [Timebased triggers are stopping when deploying a new version](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/199185684)

This seems to happen to all triggers installed via Workspace add-on: **once a Workspace add-on is updated with a new deployment, the triggers attached to older deployments stop executing**.

#### Workaround:

While at this point it's not clear whether this is expected behavior or not, a possible workaround (as explained by [Neven Subotic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69295994)) for updating a Workspace add-on without disabling the current deployment triggers is to [edit a versioned deployment](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/deployments#edit_a_versioned_deployment) instead of [creating a new one](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/deployments#create_a_versioned_deployment).

Comment: thanks - this indeed is my issue.  I get access denied when trying to access that link https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/199185684 unfortunately

Comment: @PNC My apologies, I didn't notice that issue had limited visibility. I referenced another issue in my answer, which doesn't have this limitation, in case you are interested.